# Array spontaneously emptying

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently working on an app, and for some reason an array is spontaneously emptying.

I first mention it at the top of the file:

```
let scaleTypes = [String]()
```

I then populate it (I verify it's populated by running a println of the array):

```
let scaleTypes = scaleTypesDict.valueForKey("Types")! as! [String]
println(scaleTypes.count)
```

When I access the array (when populating the contents of UITableViewCells):

```
cell.textLabel!.text = scaleTypes[indexPath.row]
```

I get `fatal error: Array index out of range`. I've done a println of the array count directly before I access the array, and found that it's emptied itself (it prints 0). The array is not mentioned elsewhere in the file. I use a similar variable name in another view controller in this app, but I highly doubt that that is causing the issue. Anyone got anything?

**EDIT:** If viewing the entire source code would help, it can be found here: https://gitlab.carson-greene.com/cgreene/scales-ios/tree/dev/Scale%20Randomizer. Unfortunately, I haven't commented things well; be warned. The file that this error happens in is the `SRSettingsViewController.swift` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring two different variables called `scaleTypes`.

The first is a member variable, which since you declare with `let` and then initialize to be empty, will never contain anything.

Then, in your `viewDidLoad` you are declaring a *new*, local variable called `scaleTypes`.  You put values in it, but it only exists while your `viewDidLoad` function is running, where it masks the member variable.  When that function exits, it disappears.

Elsewhere in other functions, when you access `scaleTypes`, you are accessing that empty member variable.

If instead you declare your member variable with `var`, and then drop the `let` in front of the assignment in `viewDidLoad`, you’ll assign the values to the member variable as you’re hoping.

Answer (score 3):

The second time you write `let scaleTypes`, you are declaring a *new* array, local to the method it's in.

Change your first `let` to `var`, and then append the values later instead of making a new array.

Also, you shouldn't use `valueForKey()`. Just use the keyed subscripts:

```
// Declare the variable as mutable
var scaleTypes = [String]()


// Later, add new variables…
if let newScales = scaleTypesDict["Types"] as? [String] {
    scaleTypes += newScales
}
```

Comment: You were 55 seconds faster :P

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `let` before populating the array, you're creating a local scoped array with the same name